# can asp.net routing 3.5 sp1 do this issue?

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have a folder(/MyFolder/) with a dedicated web.config in it that does an impersonating

In that folder I have an asp.net file that use Microsoft report viewer 8.0 named MyReport.aspx

When I view this folder on my machine, it's working perfectly without issue

When I publish my project to the dev server and I'm trying to view the report, I have an issue where the the user that run IIS doesn't have access to something, (rsAccessDenied)

Can asp.net routing cause this issue?

(I'm not at work right now so I can only go by memory so it will be hard to provide more information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, asp.net routing was causing this issue, the web.config wasn't getting loaded.

I had something like this:

> http://ip/myreport.aspx

I had to change it to

> http://ip/reports/myreport.aspx

I had to have the folder in which the web.config was located in the url

Answer (score 0):

Your impersonation is probably not set up correctly. Check the User.Identity.Name when running locally and on the server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx